How to make FireFox sync optional permissions granted to an extension
Let's say I granted permission X to an extension in one Firefox browser instance. This can be done by visiting the extensions tab in about:addons and clicking on an extension that offers optional permissions.
However, if I grant this permission and sync, my other synced Firefox browser instances won't automatically grant these permissions. How can I make Firefox sync them?

You can't. This would be really bad safety and defeat the point of such permissions in the 1st place.
